# What's the best way to stop search engine's indexing my login pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a login and registration MVC3 page in my /users directory.  I just noticed they got listed on google.

Is there a good and bad way to exclude these from google?

Comment: Find the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055316/how-to-prevent-search-engines-from-indexing-a-single-page-of-my-website

Comment: Do note though, robots.txt is only a guide line (not a law).  If the engine wants to, it can only index sites based off their robots.txt (that's a great way to find things like the admin panel, etc).  So if you are worried about security, this is only the first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a robots.txt in your root with:

```
User-agent: *   
Disallow: <your login page>
```

Comment: What kind of format should I use? For example Disallow: /users or Disallow: /users/*  ?

Comment: If you want the search engine to see what is in your directory you can use the second, if not, use the first (Disallow: /users)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: use [`robots.txt` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) also add [`rel="nofollow"` attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) for all links that lead to those pages.

Answer (score 0):

update the urls which you dont want to get indexed by google in **robots.txt**

Which you can control it from the google.com/webmasters