# Prevent Search Engine Indexes a Web Page

Tags: html, search-engine, meta-tags, robots.txt

I have a members control panel page which I don't want search engine to index.

I did the following:

1. The page is secured, if there isn't a session or password provided, then direct user to main page. Redirect the user as following:

   header("location:*HOME PAGE*"); 
   exit();
2. I put only one meta with the following attributes

> name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"

**Is this solution good enough?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent search engines from indexing a single page of my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055316/how-to-prevent-search-engines-from-indexing-a-single-page-of-my-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use robots.txt for more info see http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449

Answer (score 2):

If the page is secured, its content cannot be indexed. Even if, its content will be low rated.

How do you redirect the user? Using response header or HTML meta redirect / JavaScript?

Comment: header("location:*ADDRESS*");
exit();

Answer (score 1):

The meta data is irrelevant, if the page redirects any unidentified user to a different page, then the redirecting URL will never be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Most search engine robots (all legitimate ones) will respect this instruction. However, all you have really done is ask the robot nicely not to index your page. It does not force any sort of behaviour, merely requests it.

You could...

- Require auth to view the page. The robots will not be authenticated, and therefore cannot view the page to index it.
- Return a `404` error to any request where the `User-Agent:` string is in a list of known search engine robots. There are plenty of sites out there (such as [this one](http://www.user-agents.org/)) that will easily allow you to compile such a list.